# Table within a Table | Power BI Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, powerbi, report, builder

When writing expressions for a row in Power BI Report Builder, things line up just fine until you get data that is a lot of text.

**This is a prime example**

[image]

I have 'cangrow' to true on all of my individual cells as well as the row group / row itself. Nothing seems to fix this. Is there any way to do this so the rows expand accordingly?

**Ideally, I'd something like this.**

[image]

---

EDIT:
I believe the real problem is that I wasn't using a subtables because subtables look really bad when there are column groupings that block the merging of cells.

I'm now trying to find a way to basically add a completely separate table beneath the top table but still connected to be reported each match. First step would be find a way to have a separate data source in the subtable. Step two would be to allow the formatting of the subtable without the structure of the first.

I can't extend the subtable to the final column because of a required column group. And my expressions can't really do what I need them to without changing the dataset to something other than the main table.

Thanks for the help!

[image]

[image]

---

FINAL EDIT 2:

1) To resolve the separate dataset problem, I had to write a disgusting query to join the two sets I was using into one. I'm not sure there is a way to do that with Power BI Report Builder, although there should be.

2) I had to put the two separate tables into a list so they would be okay with formatting.

Got my problem solved, but in a round about way.

Comment: Have you tried aligning the values to the top-left of the cell?

Comment: @BJones Thanks for the reply. That makes it slightly better, but looks like this now. https://imgur.com/r758FvL -- For some reason the rows don't expand together. That's really the biggest issue. The white space you see is me manually having it do a new line a couple times. I also tried removing those and it still doesn't expand the way I feel rows should..

Comment: if you have vertical alignment set to 'top' on all cells then it should work as you expect. It might be that you have additional special characters (line feed / carriage return) in the text? If this does not work, edit your question (rather than add in comments) and show the report design. Also add borders to all cells so we can see how it is aligning better.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I think I discovered the problem is that this was a Joined LookupSet. So there wasn't a row for each result, just a text + enter. Making this a table (which is now going to be a subtable) makes things more challenging, but a bit of a different question. I'll update the main question with my structure in a moment.

Answer (score 2):

1) To resolve the separate dataset problem, I had to write a disgusting query to join the two sets I was using into one. I'm not sure there is a way to do that with Power BI Report Builder, although there should be.

2) I had to put the two separate tables into a list so they would be okay with formatting.

Got my problem solved, but in a round about way.